# Server task/daemon read Excel workbook from Sharepoint Online using MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

Requirement is for a (non Microsoft) server task to pull information, on a schedule, from an Excel workbook on Sharepoint Online.

I'd been looking into the Micrsoft Graph API, and it looked like it would work (I can navigate to the workbook using Graph Explorer, etc),  and I had been about to request a new app to be registered in Azure AD, to start testing.  I had been planning to use the "Application Permissions" option, as there won't be a logged in user.

However I just noticed in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that the workbook & worksheet API calls are not supported for the 'Application' permission type!!

Can anyone confirm that if the following would work, or not?

- Register a 'new application' in Azure AD, using 'Applicaiton Permissions' (as opposed to Delegeated)
- Obtain the client 'secret'
- Use the secret to request/obtain an access token
- Use the token on subsequent requests to read info from the Excel workbook.

If this scenario would not work, is there an alternative way for a daemon to read Excel info from SPO?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the Workbooks Graph APIs don't support application permissions.
You must have a user that consents to the application to use delegated permissions.

In this case you can use [Service Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) with the required delegated permission to access the workbooks APIs. Service Principal APIs are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Many thanks for your comment,  looks promising from a quick read. Will update here once I've had a chance to test.